# SQLServer Creating a Case in a query based on top 100 results

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, limit

I'm trying to create a SQL Server query based on the following criteria:

The query focuses on three columns: Report_Status, Error_Message, and Create_Date. The purpose of the query is to filter the top 100 most recent results based on the Create_Date. Once that's done, it needs to see if EVERY row in Report_Status in that top 100 says 'Failed' AND that Error_Message does not contain 'Placement is missing%'.

If it meets those conditions, then it needs to output the message "Potential service failure." If it doesn't meet those conditions, then it either needs to do nothing or output something normal, like "No problems found."

I figured a Case might be the best way to do this, so I tried it out. I'm having trouble getting it to work, though:

```
select Report_Status, Error_Message, Create_Date,
case
     when Report_Status = 'Failed' and Error_Message not like 'Placement is missing%' then 'Potential service failure.'
     ELSE 'No problems found.'
end
from [AUDIT_TABLE] limit 100
```

Is this the best way to approach this problem? If so, what do I need to change so this works? If it's not a good way, what's a better way to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to want something like this:

```
select (case when count(*) = 100 then 'Potential service failure.'
             else 'No problems found.'
        end) as summary
from (select a.*
      from [AUDIT_TABLE]
      order by date desc
      fetch first 100 rows only
     ) t100
where Report_Status = 'Failed' and
      Error_Message not like 'Placement is missing%'
```

Comment: When I try that query, I get a few syntax errors. I get incorrect syntax near the closing parenthesis, where, the last equals sign, and not. And if I try to run it anyways, it says "Incorrect syntax near 'limit'." All I've done is taken what you gave me and plugged in the correct table/column names--is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I also went ahead and typed the query out manually just to make sure there weren't any spaces messing things up, but I still get the exact same syntax problems mentioned above.

Comment: OK, I just realized I accidentally listed this as a MySQL query instead of a SQLServer query. Does that change things?

Comment: The only difference is that the standard SQL clause `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY` is `LIMIT 100` in MySQL at the end of the query and `TOP (100)` in the select clause in SQL Server.

Comment: @JeremiahWilliams . . . The question was originally *tagged* and *titled* for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working with a coworker to solve this. Gordon Linoff's CASE section was great, but we changed how we searched for the most recent 100 records by also using the Report_ID field.

```
select
 (case when count(*) = 100 then 'Potential failure.'
        else 'No problems found.'
    end) as Result
 from Audit_Table
where Report_Status = 'fail' 
    and  Error_Message not like 'Placement is missing%'
    and  Report_ID >= (select min(Report_ID) from (select top 100 * from Audit_Table  order by Report_ID desc ) t100)
```

Comment: Using the `Report_ID` is a good idea. The clause doesn't have to be so complicated, though: `and report_id in (select top (100) report_id from audit_table order by report_id desc)`. But I like Gordon's `FROM` clause even better, as you it accesses the table only once.